# Difference between CR3 value and pgd_t

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86, x86-64, kernel-module

I am playing around, and trying to perform manually a page table walk on my x86_64 CPU, with Linux installed.

I want to try and get the same value by using the Linux API, and by manually looking at the page table values.

I found here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand006.html that the value of CR3 should be equal to current->mm->pgd. But it is not:

```
current->mm->pgd = 0x457ec6067
cr3 = 0x45700a006
```

current->mm->pgd seems to stay constant across runs. What am I missing?

Thanks!

edit. This is my code:

```
 __asm__ __volatile__ (
    "mov %%cr3, %%rax\n\t"
    "mov %%rax, %0\n\t" 
    : "=m" (cr3)  
    :
    : "%rax"  
     );
pr_err("cr3 = 0x%lx ", (long)cr3);
pr_err("\tcurrent->mm->pgd = 0x%lx\n", current->mm->pgd->pgd);
```

Comment: What is your Linux kernel version?

Comment: 4.15.0-45-generic with KPTI off (it's the i9-9900K that has hardware mitigations)

Comment: Are you reading `mm->pgd` and `cr3` immediately one after the other? Isn't it possible that the location of the top-level page table has changed between reading `mm->pgd` and `cr3`?

Comment: The code you’ve shown doesn’t qualify as reading cr3 and pgd immediately one after the other. There’s I/O, probably including a system call, between them.

Comment: @user1637056: So the first `pr_err`  runs before you read `current->mm->pgd->pgd`.  What happens if you use one call to that function with a format string that handles both operands?

Comment: The reference you linked doesn’t talk about four-level page tables. Do you have a reference that says how pgd is used in x86-64?

Comment: All the code is running inside the Linux kernel.
If I put both in the same pr_err line it is the same.
As far as I understand, the reference I put is the generic Linux-handling-paging reference

Comment: Does `current->mm->pgd` contain the virtual address or the physical address of the top-level page table? What is the value of `virt_to_phys(current->mm->pgd)`?

Comment: As far as I know, current->mm->pgd should be physical. Regardles, I printed the values you sked for: cr3 = 0x456e2a004, current->mm->pgd = 0x453a2f067,  virt_to_phys(current->mm->pgd) = 0x680b13a2f067

Comment: According to the [build_cr3](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/arch/x86/include/asm/tlbflush.h#L121) function, `cr3 = __sme_pa(pgd) | kern_pcid(asid)`. ASID is only the 12 least significant bits. SME is only supported on AMD. On Intel, it is simple equal to `__pa(pgd)`, which I don't think is equal to `pgd`. There is some calculation involved here.

Comment: I saw that, but I should have at least 40 bits in common (the 40 bits I need to find the PML4), I don't see even that

Comment: I ran a quick test on 4.4.0-141-generic (with PTI enabled) and found that `cr3` is equal to `pgd`.

Comment: @HadiBrais :I suspect what is going on there is that `pgd` by itself is a virtual address. Linux maps the page structures into virtual memory so that they tables can be modified easily. They pass around a virtual address and then convert it to its physical address when storing it in CR3.I suspect that with x86-64 Linux systems there is a simple calculation from virtual to physical (as I recall x86-64 Linux pretty much maps all the physical memory it can into virtual address space)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with Linux 4.14, `pgd` can be translated to the physical page address of the page global directory to be used in `cr3` by calling `__sme_pa` and passing to it `pgd`. Note that the least significant 12 bits of the returned value (which represent ASID) are zero. So the ASID has to be OR'ed with it.

Before Linux 4.14, `__pa` can be used instead of `__sme_pa` which was not supported. Note that `__pa` is equivalent to `__sme_pa` on Intel processors because SME is only available on AMD processors.

At least since Linux 2.6, `pgd` and `cr3` may or may not be equivalent depending on two factors:

- Whether `pgd` is larger than the virtual base address of the kernel image `__START_KERNEL_map`.
- `phys_base`, which is the difference between the compile-time physical base address of the kernel image and the run-time physical base address of the image. If the image has been relocated, `phys_base` would not be zero.

The translation process is performed by a function called [__phys_addr](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/arch/x86/mm/physaddr.c#L14) which you can refer to to follow the following examples.

I've tested this on two systems. On Linux 4.4.0, I got the following values:

```
cr3                 = 0x3581E000
pgd                 = 0x3581E000
__pa(pgd)           = 0x3581E000
__START_KERNEL_map  = 0x80000000
phys_base           = 0x00000000
```

In this case, `pgd` and `cr3` are equivalent. On Linux 4.15:

```
cr3                 = 0x8980A005
pgd                 = 0xC980A000
__pa(pgd)           = 0x8980A000
__START_KERNEL_map  = 0x80000000
phys_base           = 0xEC000000
```